# Recover data from unreadable NTFS partition

Tags: boot, hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery

I have an Asus laptop with Windows and Ubuntu alongside. When I try to boot Windows, it gets to the Windows logo and restarts automatically. Looks like recovery starts but all the recovery options fail. Not even command prompt works. Started startup recovery which ran for a day and did not yield any results. Inserted flash with recovery image—not readable. In Windows recovery option "recovery image" is not visible.  CD-ROM—dead.... Ubuntu can not access the HDD.

Ubuntu error message:

> ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation for more details.

[Here](http://i963.photobucket.com/albums/ae120/IHARBABITSKI/Myproblem_zps2d491f2f.png) is my screenshot in Ubuntu. Recovery mode in Windows offers to load drivers.
Tried ntfsfix, and recover superblocks... did not work.

Have no clue what I should do. Please help, and be specific if you can as I do not know what am I doing at all!

Answer (score 3):

If you have an option to remove the HDD and connect it to another PC with Ubuntu, then please do and install the `testdisk` package which includes `photorec` (File Recovery) and `testdisk` (Partition Recovery).

`sudo apt-get install testdisk` (In case you do not have it)

NOTE: Do not recover the files you get with testdisk/photorec on the same HDD you are recovering from. This will most likely mess stuff up.

You need another HDD to recover the files to.

I also recommend running `fsck` to check that HDD for problems. If `fsck` says it is ok, then at least at hardware level you are ok. Software level it is better with either the **ntfs-3g** tools like `ntfsck` and `ntfsfix`. To run `fsck` do:

`sudo fsck /dev/sda2` but be sure to boot either from the Ubuntu you have already installed (If it correctly loads up) or from a LiveCD/LiveUSB. If not, then proceed from another PC. The reason I mention is fsck is to not only verify that the HDD is ok at the hardware level (Because of so many bad sectors and the warnings you got) but also to know that, if fsck can read it, it means you can actually save the information in it.

Just in case, here are 2 good links to recovery information:

[Fsck vs Chkdsk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174937/main-differences-between-fsck-and-chkdsk/174949#174949)

[Tools to Diagnose](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75325/tools-to-diagnose-ubuntu-problems/79357#79357)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a liveUSB or liveDVD, install `testdisk` and try to recover data from testdisk.